# Django - intercepting a model change with the pre_save() hook

Tags: django

I was wondering, I have the following `pre_save()` signal intercept:

```
def model_pre_save(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if instance.uuid:
        my_model = Model.objects.get(uuid=instance.uuid)

    if my_model.has_signed_exception:
        # Once signed, no one can overwrite this value:
        instance.has_signed_exception = True 

pre_save.connect(model_pre_save, sender=Model)
```

I was wondering - the instanced that is sent seems to be the instance that is being updated - but is there an argument I can use to get the exisiting instance, rather than making a further DB call on every save?

Comment: Is `instance` a `Model`?

Comment: I don't think its possible to get Model instance without making additional db call.

Comment: @schillingt Yes...

Comment: Is something else setting `has_signed_exception` then? It seems like both `instance` and `my_model` are the same thing.

Comment: @schillingt Yes - so the field is being moved from a legacy transition system, a bookings system whereby a booking could have been made on the legacy system for a future date. The system which handles this signing exception is the new system. We don't want the old system updating the new...

Comment: Instance could be different. But essentially, once that BooleanField is set to True, it must always stay True.

Comment: Either I don't understand your use case or this isn't doing what you want. However, the `instance` that's provided by `pre_save` is the existing DB record if you're updating it. If you're creating a new one, then obviously it won't exist. If you're trying to handle a race condition situation, you may want to use a `.filter(has_signed_exception=False).update(has_signed_exception=True)` then check the returned value to see if it updated a record.